# preg_match возвращает массив с дублями

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Шаблон:

```
"(?P<name>[^/\?]+)/(?P<age>[^/\?]+)"
```

Данные:

```
"john/23"
```

Возвращает:

```
array(4) {
    ["name"]=> string(4) "john" 
    [0]=> string(4) "john" 
    ["age"]=> string(2) "23" 
    [1]=> string(2) "23" 
}
```

Нужно что бы в массиве не дублировались значения.

```
array_unique()
```

Для моего решения не подходит, так как данные иногда могут совпадать.

Comment: Вопрос только в одном - а вы уверены, что дело в регулярном выражении. Просто  любопытно откуда regexp мог взять  строки `name` и `age`  из строки `john/23`

Comment: @newman поправил regex.

Comment: @donttime А как вы добились такого результата. preg_match помимо приведенного вами должен был в array[0] вернуть целиком совпавшую строку, т.е. john/23. И зачем использовать именнованные подвыражения ? preg_match с именованными всегда себя так ведет, возвращая их и по номеру и по имени.

Comment: @Mike в том то и дело что нужны именованные, потому что иногда они передаются в колбэки в виде параметров, а иногда просто используются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов несколько.

Первый – не использовать именованные подмаски и тогда у вас будет обычный индексный массив.

Второй – обработать текущий массив удалив все числовые ключи:

```
$newArray = array_filter($matches, function($k) {
    return !is_numeric($k);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
var_dump($newArray);
```

Третий – не использовать вообще регулярку, если вам нудно просто разбит строку с одним единственным разделителем:

```
$newArray = explode('/', "john/23");
var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: Разделителей много.

Comment: @donttime первый или второй вариант

Answer (score 2):

используйте

```
explode('/',$string)
```

вернет не ассоциативный массив вида

```
array (
  0 => 'josh',
  1 => 23
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Регулярным выражением тут ничего не сделаешь. Как вариант можно пробежаться по массиву и сделать unset для всех элементов у которых индекс является целым числом.

Можно через банальный foreach или через array_filter

Comment: Ну если только перебором. Потому что array_filter бывает себя ведет не корректно при добавлении и удалении элементов.

Comment: @donttime так при использовании array_filter ничего не надо делать с исходным массивом. Достаточно в callback говорить о том проходит этот элемент или нет. Ну и дополнительный параметр позволяет передавать в callback ключи массива. Т.е. по сути callback это вызов is_int

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще вариант позволяющий сохранить структуризацию регулярного выражения за счет выноса именованных групп в блок `(?(DEFINE)...)`, а для захваченного текста задать новые группы, которые будут помещены в результат без дублирования:

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?P<name>[^\/\?]+)
  (?P<age>[^\/\?]+)
  )
((?P>name)) # group 1
\/
((?P>age))  # group 2
```

https://regex101.com/r/fG9lW1/1

Результат:

```
array(2) {
    [1]=> string(4) "john" 
    [2]=> string(2) "23" 
}
```